# How to make that scanf is optionally ignoring one of its conversion specifiers?

Tags: c, string, input, scanf, language-lawyer

```
char value1[10];
int value2;
int value3 = 0;
if (!scanf("%s %d %d", &value1[0], &value2, &value3)) {
    scanf("%s %d", &value1[0], &value2);
}
;
```

I am trying to use `scanf` to insert 3 values, but if received 2 it will take in 2 instead. I'm not able to find any answer how to use `scanf`. I've been trying to use `fgets` but value in stdin remains.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of converted items, so `!scanf` does not look right. (There's also `EOF` to consider, which is a truthy negative value.) Anyway, save the return value, `n = scanf(...)`, accept 2 and 3 as valid values and if the value is 2, set `value3` to a default value. You only get one pass through the data.

Comment: As @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio hints at in his comments, consider using `fgets()` for user input instead of `scanf()`. `scanf()` is ill-suited to deal with user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%s %d %d", &value1[0], &value2, &value3)
```

The problem is `scanf()` can´t ignore the third conversion specifier. It still keeps trying to catch the decimal input for the third argument, `value3`.

To catching the whole input as string first and then later split the content of this string into each own object may be a better alternative.

`fgets()` is a litte more safer than `scanf()` when taking user input so I´ll use `fgets()`.

```
char* fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

With `fgets()` you need to define the amount of characters to read (`num`), which is a great feature for maintaining security, but in this case we don´t know what a user potentially will input as integer for the decimal input requests. If we specify to less characters for the digits, the rest digits will be left in `stdin`.

A workaround would be to specify the total amount of digits possible for representing integers of type `int` in decimal notation in the call to `fgets()`.

These would be 10 digits for the total number of "2,147,483,647" on 64-bit architectures or 5 digits for the total number of "32,767" on 32-bit architectures. I go with the 64-bit case for now.

So `10` (value1) + `10` (value2) + `10` (value3) + `2`space characters between value1 and value2 and between value2 and value3 + the terminating `\0` for a string = `33` characters. Note that `fgets()` also reads the entered newline `\n` (but we later discard that from the string easily) so we need even one character more; it is in total `34` characters:

```
char buffer[34];
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
```

After that we need to proof how many content we have in the string stored in `buffer`. We can proof it implicitly by counting the space characters:

```
unsigned int mark;

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < (sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]) - 1)); i++)
{
   if(buffer[i] == ' ')
     mark++;
}
```

Thereafter we need to transfer/convert the individual content pieces inside the string in `buffer` to the appropriate own objects by using `sscanf()`. If we now have 2 space characters in the string, we can use 3 conversion specifiers in a `sscanf` command, else we have appropriate `sscanf()`s:

```
if(mark == 2)
{
    sscanf(buffer,"%s %d %d", value1, &value2, &value3);
}
   else if(mark == 1)
   {
      sscanf(buffer,"%s %d", value1, &value2);
   }
      else if(mark == 0)
      {
         sscanf(buffer,"%s", value1);
      }
         else
         {
            printf("The input entered is not valid!\n");
            printf("Please try again!\n");
         }
```

The whole code is then:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char value1[10];
    int value2;
    int value3;
    unsigned int mark;
    char buffer[34];

    for(;;)
    {
       fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
       buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;

       mark = 0;

       for(unsigned int i = 0; i < ((sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]) - 1)); i++)
       {
          if(buffer[i] == ' ')
          mark++;
       }

       if(mark == 2)
       {
          sscanf(buffer,"%s %d %d", value1, &value2, &value3);
          break;
       }
          else if(mark == 1)
          {
             sscanf(buffer,"%s %d", value1, &value2);
             break;
          }
             else if(mark == 0)
             {
                sscanf(buffer,"%s", value1);
                break;
             }
                else
                {
                   printf("The input entered is not valid!\n");
                   printf("Please try again!\n");
                }
    }

    printf("value1 = %s\n", value1);

    if(mark == 1 || mark == 2)
    printf("value2 = %d\n", value2);

    if(mark == 2)
    printf("value3 = %d\n", value3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pmg The 5000 spaces isn´t possible since `fgets()` only consumes 32; appending the `\0` as 33rd. But I got what you mean. I build a safety in which it proofs if the input string provided by `fgets()`  has too much space characters in it.

Comment: `fgets()` has no problem with the size of user input; it requires the code to specify the size of the storage buffer. If user input is too large for the buffer, `fgets()` safely stops fetching input and null-terminates the buffer. Extra input is left in the input stream; it is up to the programmer to handle the unread input, but not an overflow issue. BTW, better to not hardcode the size argument for `buffer` when `buffer` is an array: `fgets(buffer,33,stdin)` --> `fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)`.

Comment: @exnihilo 2 very good catches. I took them into the answer. Yeah, I confused input in stdin and storing into a buffer. Thank you very much or the hint.

Answer (score 3):

```
char value1[10]; int value2; int value3 = 0;
if (!scanf("%s %d %d", &value1[0], &value2, &value3)) { scanf("%s %d", &value1[0], &value2); } ;
```

One tiny thing: Don't use `&value1[0]`, use `value1`. An array will decay into a pointer to its first element and, notionally, it's `value1` that you want to store the string in.

Second, you need call `scanf` just once and look at its return value. That will tell you how many values were read in. In this case, you don't really care, so you could use:

```
if (scanf("%s %d %d", value1, &value2, &value3) < 2)
    { /* error handling */ }
else // we read in 2 or 3 entries, life is good
    { /* success handling */ }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have one more problem, while doing it this method, there be always a new line even if i clear it using getchar(); any ideas on how can I solve this? thank you!

Comment: This does not solve the OP´s problem. He asks for a method to skip the consumption for the third conversion specifier. With this method `scanf` still try to get an input for the the last `%d`. Also didn´t you meant `scanf("%s %d %d", value1, &value2, &value3) <= 2)`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio: if the input is like `"foobar 17 quux"`, or `"foobar 42<EOF>"` the `scanf()` in the answer above will stop at the second conversion specifier (and return `2`).

Comment: But I do not consider irregular input. I consider input in the form it is expected according to the conversion specifiers and arguments, like f.e.: `hello 27`. In this case `scanf` still keeps scanning for catching a decimal integer.

Comment: @pmg I copied the source code from the OP and made a test program. It still tries to catch the decimal.

Comment: In the meantime, `scanf("%s %d %d", value1, &value2, &value3) < 2)` is right, this was a mistake from me, but considering that it always seeks for the second decimal input and don´t stop until it catched it, the `if` condition will mostly always be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `scanf()` more than once. When the second `scanf()` executes the data is no longer in the input buffer.

```
char value1[10];
int value2, value3;
int n = scanf("%9s%d%d", value1, &value2, &value3);
// scanf() returns the number of assignments it made, or EOF in case of failure
switch (n) {
    default: fprintf(stderr, "scanf failure\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0: strcpy(value1, "default"); /* fall-through */
    case 1: value2 = 42; /* fall-through */
    case 2: value3 = -1; /* fall-through */
    case 3: break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For flexibility in parsing input, prefer `fgets()` to fetch lines of input, and `sscanf()` to parse that input. This allows repeated scans on the same input, when necessary.

To use `fgets()`, an input buffer is needed. The `fgets()` function takes an argument describing the size of that input buffer, and reads at most one less character from the input stream. In the event that the user input is larger than this limit, extra input remains in the input stream. This may cause problems for later IO operations, so robust code should handle these extra characters (by reading and either using or discarding them). Simpler code that does not need robustness can simply choose a generously sized input buffer that is unlikely to be overburdened by trusted users. The code below chooses a buffer size of `BUFSIZE` to be 1024, which should be plenty of extra room, even if a user inadvertently types too many characters at the end of input. Note also that, when there is space for it, the `\n` character marking the end of a line is read from the input stream and stored in the input buffer. This newline often needs to be removed from the buffer, but in cases involving `sscanf()` often no further action is needed since the newline should not interfere with scanning.

The `sscanf()` function (in fact, all `fscanf()` family functions) respond to the `%n` directive, which writes the number of characters read from the input up to the occurrence of this directive into a provided integer variable. For `sscanf()`, this effectively means that when `%n` is encountered in the format string, the index of the character following the last character read is stored in this provided integer variable.

The code below makes use of this `%n` facility by first doing `num_assigned = sscanf(buffer, "%9s %d%n", value1, &value2, &scan_loc)`. Here the first two values, which are always expected, are scanned, and the number of characters read to this point is stored in `scan_loc`. The `num_assigned` variable holds the number of assignments made by `sscanf()`, which should be 2. If this is not true, then the program exits with an error message; otherwise the code continues by attempting to parse the rest of the input string. Here, `buffer` points to the first character of the `buffer[]` array, and `buffer + scan_loc` points to the character *following the last character read by `sscanf()`*. That is, the second call to `sscanf()` picks up where the first call left off. If this second call successfully makes an assignment to `value3`, then `num_assigned` is incremented.

Note that `sscanf()` can return 0 or -1 when no assignment is made, depending on circumstances. For this reason, code like: `num_assigned += sscanf(buffer + scan_loc, "%d", &value3)` is no good since failure to make an assignment could result in *decrementing* `num_assigned`. Note also that `fgets()` is not susceptible to buffer overflow problems when the correct size of the input buffer is provided. If `buffer` is an array, then `sizeof buffer` will always provide the correct size (if `buffer` were a pointer instead, size would have to be obtained another way). But, `sscanf()` is still susceptible to buffer overflow when using the `%s` directive. Always specify a maximum field width when using `%s` (or the `%[]` scanset directive, for that matter) to avoid buffer overflow when input is larger than expected. A `\0` terminator is *always* written by `sscanf()` with the `%s` directive, so to make room use `%9s` for an array like `char value1[10]` with a capacity for 10 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>        // for exit() and EXIT_FAILURE

#define BUFSIZE  1024

int main(void) {
    char value1[10];
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;

    char buffer[BUFSIZE];  // generous user input buffer
    int scan_loc = 0;      // scan location in buffer
    int num_assigned = 0;  // number of values assigned by sscanf()

    // fetch user input: parse only if fgets is successful
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) != NULL) {

        // attempt to make first two assignments
        num_assigned = sscanf(buffer, "%9s %d%n", value1, &value2, &scan_loc);
        if (num_assigned == 2) {

            // success: attempt to make third assignment
            int final_assignment = sscanf(buffer + scan_loc, "%d", &value3);
            if (final_assignment == 1) {
                ++num_assigned;
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Input error: %d values read\n", num_assigned);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("value1: %s, value2: %d", value1, value2);
        if (num_assigned == 3) {
            printf(", value3: %d\n", value3);
        } else {
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample executions:

```
$ ./a.out 
test2 42
value1: test2, value2: 42
$ ./a.out 
test3 12 34
value1: test3, value2: 12, value3: 34
```